# How to control sidekiq queues concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Assuming I have  5 workers `A` , `B` , `C` , `D` , `E`. The first 3 worker belongs to `safe` queue and last two worker belongs `unsafe` queue.  The `unsafe` queue worker shouldn't run parallely and `safe` worker queue can run parallely. And, yes  two queues can run parallely.

How do i configure this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two Sidekiq Process for safe and unsafe queues.
And set the concurrency of the unsafe queue to 1. This will make sure, the unsafe jobs don't run simultaneously.

Comment: how can I set concurrency depending on queue?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Split them into two separate projects and set the concurrency on the unsafe to 1.

**Option 2**: The sidekiq-unique-jobs gem is not working so well anymore, otherwise, I would recommend it.  If you care to fix the issues it's encountering and use it that would be my preference.

- https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs